# Ubuntu cloud server run node.js application

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, apache2

I have a ubuntu server on the cloud where i have my app running.

I am having a few issues:

1. first when clicking on the url it shows all the files
2. How do i get it to render the correct page in my case login page?

I use the following command to run node: node server.js

Any ideas would be great

Answer (score 0):

Looks insufficient information in your question. Below is the steps what i done on my VPS.

As i came form ruby background and done some work on Nginx combo with thin, unicorn and passenger So I preferred to use Nginx as a front end server, which in this case proxies the requests to a node.js server.

Below is Nginx Config:

```
upstream shop {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
  listen 80;# default deferred;
  server_name localhost;
  root /var/www/shop/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @shop;

  location @shop {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://shop; 
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
```

}

Comment: You could also just use Phusion Passenger with Nginx. That makes everything a lot easier and will reduce the above config snippets by 60%. See https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Phusion-Passenger%3A-Node.js-tutorial